# How to get Visual Studio to recognize multiple project resource files

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

I have a Windows project in Visual Studio 2010 in which I store all images in the project's resource file that Visual Studio created for me. However, it's getting cluttered and I'd like to separate images into multiple resource files if possible. I created a new resource file, but Visual Studio doesn't recognize it when I go to the form designer and try to change an image. The only file that comes up under the Project resource files available are MyProject\Resources.resx. The one that I just created isn't there.

Any idea why it doesn't show up? I tried putting the resource under the My.Resources namespace as well as change the namespace and I also made it public. It still doesn't show up.

[image: Select Resource screen]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A project only has a single default resource file.  You can add additional non-default resource files to the project at any time.  Additional resources files will NOT be placed in the "My Project" folder.  They will simply be added to the project like other files are.

You can refer to these new resources the same way you refer to others.  Instead of accessing the resources through "My.Resources.", you will find the other resource files under "My.Resources.[Resource File Name]".

**EDIT:**  A resource file needs to be in the root of your project if you want to reference it from a PictureBox control.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I know I can reference them in the code under My.Resources.[Resource File Name], but is there a way to get the resource files to be available from the "Select Resource" screen? I've attached at image to the original post to show you what I'm talking about.

Comment: When you go to the Image property on a PictureBox control and click the "..." you can select any of the other resources files in the "Project resource file:" dropdown.  I'm using VS2010 SP1.

Comment: I figured it out. Apparently you have to have the resource file in the root of the project and not in any folder within the project or it doesn't seem to show up. That kind of stinks, but I'll live with it. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You won't see the resource in the dialog, but if you move the resource file to the root, then pick it in your dialog, then move the file back to where you want it, it will continue to work.  It's just a bug in the picture chooser dialog.