# Visual Studio 2017: too many resources

Tags: c++, mfc, visual-studio-2017

We are working on big project in Visual Studio 2017, with approx 11000 resources.
Resources, in that context, can be string tables, dialogs, bitmaps, ribbons, etc.
All the resource ids are saved in the same Resource.h file, because there is only a single resource script file (Project.rc).

The problem we are facing is that when we create a new resource (e.g. a dialog), the Resource.h is being modified to include the new id and, therefore, every file that includes this Resource.h needs to be recompiled. This leads to a high compilation time (~20 min), even if adding only a message.

Is it possible to create multiple .rc files in the same project?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

**-- EDIT --**

TL;DR: how can I create a new .rc so I can place there my resources and avoid recompiling all the resources of my teammates every single time I add a new resource?

Comment: You need to split your project up, having all your resources in a single resource file creates a single dependency for all your code, your resources should be associated with the logical units of your code

Comment: Thank you @EdChum, I understand what you said, but how can I add a second .rc? I don't think it's a good idea to create a new project for every dialog and its logic.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7100248/how-to-get-visual-studio-to-recognize-multiple-project-resource-files I'm not asking to create a project for every dialog but your project can probably be split up to reduce the dependency, this is too broad to discuss here but clearly 11000 resources is far too many, you need to rethink your current design

Comment: @EdChum I've seen the post before, it doesn't really answer how can you create a new .rc or, at least, I don't understand the method. You are right in the "rethink your design" thing, but it's impossible due to company limitations. My question is not broad, it's concise: how can I create a new .rc so I can place there my resources and avoid recompiling all the resources of my teammates every single time I add a new resource? Anyway, thank you for pointing me in a good direction.

Comment: You can create `myresource.rc2` then include that file in your main .rc file (.rc2 files have to be edited manually, so it's not ideal for dialog resources) But that won't help with speeding up the compile time. If you change one resource ID, then you have to compile all the files which have `#include "resource.h"` So you also have to add a separate header file. Make sure these header files are included in *.cpp file only when they are needed.